# Android DatePicker Year not updating

Tags: android, datepicker

I am experiencing what I believe is a DatePicker bug.

I have a date picker dialog:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"    
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    >
    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/datePicker" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:calendarViewShown="false"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" 
        >    
    </DatePicker>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"     
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        >

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/cmdCancel" 
            android:text="@android:string/cancel" 
            android:layout_width="0dp" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".5"          
            >
        </Button>

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/cmdOK"
            android:text="@android:string/ok" 
            android:layout_width="0dp" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".5"          
            >
        </Button>

        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I get a handle to it and display the dialog when a date entry is required. The `Ok` button code is such:

```
Button cmdOK = (Button)dialogDate.findViewById(R.id.cmdOK);
cmdOK.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {                       
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {                   
        try {

            int day = datePicker.getDayOfMonth();
            int month = datePicker.getMonth()+1; // offset index
            int year = datePicker.getYear();
            String dob = month+"/"+day+"/"+year;
            txtDOB.setText(dob);

            closeDialogDate();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }                                   
 });
```

Everything works as expected sans one scenario and I can repeat the behavior.

**The issue:**

If I select the year by tapping on the value and get a number keypad, enter the date and it's the LAST THING ENTERED, whether I hit `done` on the keypad or just hit the `Ok` button, executing the processing, the year does not get updated correctly.  If I select day or month values before hitting `Ok` the year is correctly updated.  If I use the spinners, the year is updated correctly.  The only time the bug appears is when it's the LAST and directly entered value.

What am I not doing correctly?

**This is NOT a -1900 issue.  With the provided screen shot, the value is changed to 1990 and 1984 is what is returned - the default value.**

[image]

**Other references:**

- OS v4.0.4 (Ice Cream Sandwich)
- Target API 4.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like the button click callback is being triggered before the manually-entered year has a chance to save to the DatePicker.

I believe the Month and Day fields "work" because when you fill in the value, they automatically refocus to the next field (which saves the value to the DatePicker). However, I was able to force the Day field to behave the way you describe by inputting a single-digit day, closing the keyboard, and then pressing "OK"—the day value was not saved.

Let's take a look at the source of DatePickerDialog's "OK" method:

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    if (mCallBack != null) {
        mDatePicker.clearFocus();
        mCallBack.onDateSet(mDatePicker, mDatePicker.getYear(), 
        mDatePicker.getMonth(), mDatePicker.getDayOfMonth());
    }
}
```

Since your buttons appear to be custom layout items (i.e. you're not using an actual DatePickerDialog), you should probably call `clearFocus()` on your DatePicker before getting the date. Or, use a DatePickerDialog.

Comment: Only the year value behaves this way.  The month and day work fine in any order.  Very curious.

Comment: I was able to reproduce with Day also, see my updated answer.

Comment: Perhaps the question should be `how to force field update` on DatePicker?

Comment: I don't think you can, but it should update when you press "Done" on the keyboard...at least, my example code does. Are you saying if you press "Done" and then "OK", the year is still messed up?

Comment: Yes.  Again only with year - The `Done` key is not available with the `Day`, only `Next`.  You're free to test the `Done` key as described.  It fails every time.  If I select another value field like `Month` or `Day` it will get updated.

Comment: In my implementation, the "Done" key closes the keyboard and updates the year. The dialog remains open and if I press "OK", the date has been updated properly. It's only when I press "OK" without having used "Done" that it fails to update. Are there any actions tied to your IME "Done" button? It doesn't automatically close the dialog, right?

Comment: No, the `Done` key does not close the dialog but does hide the keyboard.  I have no explicit handler for the keyboard in any respect to this dialog and DatePicker.  Understand, the `DatePicker Year` field gets updated with the `Done` key, but the `datePicker.getYear()` returns 1984 and not 1990 - or any other four digit number entered.  In other words, my `TextView` displays the wrong year.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63733/discussion-between-justin-powell-and-android-addict).